# Concat pandas dataframes without following a certain sequence

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have data files which are converted to pandas dataframes which sometimes share column names while others sharing time series index, which all I wish to combine as one dataframe based on both column and index whenever matching. Since there is no sequence in naming they appear randomly for concatenation. If two dataframe have different columns are concatenated along `axis=1` it works well, but if the resulting dataframe is combined with new df with the column name from one of the earlier merged pandas dataframe, it fails to concat. For example with these data [files](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tldju1uil4yfjqs/example_files.zip?dl=0) :

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('0.csv', index_col=0, parse_dates=True, infer_datetime_format=True)
df2 = pd.read_csv('1.csv', index_col=0, parse_dates=True, infer_datetime_format=True)
df3 = pd.read_csv('2.csv', index_col=0, parse_dates=True, infer_datetime_format=True)

data1 = pd.DataFrame()
file_list = [df1, df2, df3]  # fails
# file_list = [df2, df3,df1]   # works
for fn in file_list:
   if data1.empty==True or fn.columns[1] in data1.columns:
        data1 = pd.concat([data1,fn])
   else:
        data1 = pd.concat([data1,fn], axis=1)
```

I get `ValueError: Plan shapes are not aligned` when I try to do that. In my case there is no way to first load all the DataFrames and check their column names. Having that I could combine all `df` with same column names to later only `concat` these resulting dataframes with different column names along `axis=1` which I know always works as shown below. However, a solution which requires preloading all the DataFrames and rearranging the sequence of concatenation is not possible in my case (it was only done for a working example above). I need a flexibility in terms of in whichever sequence the information comes it can be concatenated with the larger dataframe `data1`. Please let me know if you have a suggested suitable approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go through the loop step by step, you can find that in the first iteration it goes into the `if`, so `data1` is equal to `df1`. In the second iteration it goes to the `else`, since `data1` is not empty and `''Temperature product barrel ValueY''` is not in `data1.columns`. 
After the else, `data1` has some duplicated column names. In every row of the duplicated column names. (one of the 2 columns is `Nan`, the other one is a float). This is the reason why `pd.concat()` fails.

You can aggregate the duplicate columns before you try to concatenate to get rid of it:

```
for fn in file_list:
    if data1.empty==True or fn.columns[1] in data1.columns:
        # new: 
        data1 = data1.groupby(data1.columns, axis=1).agg(np.nansum)
        data1 = pd.concat([data1,fn])
    else:
        data1 = pd.concat([data1,fn], axis=1)
```

After that, you would get

```
data1.shape
(30, 23)
```